# Installing Qubes 3.1 : boot process freezes after Qubes logo blinks

Tags: system-installation, qubes

After burning Qubes iso on a USB stick using `dd` I boot it in UEFI mode and I got a problem with the following symptom :

If I select `Verify source and install Qubes` the process freezes after the test passes.
If I select `Install Qubes` I got this :

```
Ignoring BGRT : invalid status 0 (expected 1)
mce : unable to init device /dev/mcelog (rc:-16)
/etc/vconsole.cong line 1: 1=: command not found
/etc/vconsole.cong line 1: 1=: command not found
sd 4:0:0:0:[sdb] no caching mode page found
sd 4:0:0:0:[sdb] assuming drive cache : write through
mount: /dev/sdb is write protected, mounting read-only
```

And then the booting process freezes completely and I can only reboot with ctrl+alt+del. I have to add that the Qubes graphical logo blinks very briefly before it comes back to the command line and freezes.

Any idea on what is happening ? Is there a way to activate a verbose mode so there is more detail on the failure reason ?

Comment: It may be totally unrelated, but that file `/etc/vconsole.conf`, it looks like there might be some variables in there being set, but with the variable name prepended by a `$` (e.g. `$FONT=`).

Answer (score 0):

**As there is some common bug in UEFI implementation, you may find workaround in [this article](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/uefi-troubleshooting/).**

Press `Ctrl+Alt+F2` for shell, `F3` for log or `F4` for storage log. I assume it may be a kernel-related issue, too. Consider making a newer **Qubes 3.2** install using `dd` or try rufus. You can still look on [hardware compatibility list](https://www.qubes-os.org/hcl/).